# Dock "Turn Hiding On" programmatically from within an app

Tags: swift, macos, dock

If you secondary-click on the Dock you can click the `Turn Hiding On` option to automatically hide the Dock. Alternatively, you can go to `System Preferences > Dock` and click the `Automatically hide and show the Dock`.

I want to mimic that functionality from within an app I am making (which is basically a status bar icon app) and preferably in Swift.

---

The code I have written so far to turn on the Dock Automatic Hiding functionality is the following:

```
// Update the value for key "autohide" in com.apple.dock.plist, located in ~/Library/Preferences/.
var dict = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().persistentDomainForName("com.apple.dock")
dict.updateValue(true, forKey: "autohide")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setPersistentDomain(dict, forName: "com.apple.dock")

// Send notification to the OS.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    CFNotificationCenterPostNotification(CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter(), "com.apple.dock.prefchanged", nil, nil, true)
}
```

The first part of the code updates a value in a plist file and I have confirmed that that is working. The second part sends a notification to the OS to tell it that a value has been changed in that plist, which I have also confirmed to be working.

However, these two things are not making the Dock hide, making me believe I need to do something else. Or made my approach to the problem is wrong? How do I make the Dock start hiding?

PS: I have read something about a private, undocumented API called CoreDock, but I would like to avoid going that way, as it may cause many problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly better to use AppleScript or the Scripting Bridge to do this. The following script turns Dock autohiding on:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set autohide of dock preferences to true
end tell
```

You can run that using `NSAppleScript`.

Comment: Sweet. That worked and I only need a couple of lines of code with `NSAppleScript`.

Comment: With Mojave's AppleEvent Sandboxing, which causes the user to be asked whether automation via AppleEvents be allowed, I would rather not use AppleEvents.  (Both AppleScript and Scripting Bridge use AppleEvents).  Is there a way to autohide the Dock for all apps that doesn't require the use of AppleEvents -- such as Cocoa or Accessibility?

Comment: NSAppleScript and OSAScript classes available from Objective-C and Swift both have memory leaks, so I'm using the command-line tool osascript called from Swift.